# Xcode 9 and iOS 11 SDK:UIToolbar buttons actions are triggering

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, xcode9

I have UIToolbar which I am initialising with Nib using following statement.

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyToolbar" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0] // this is an instance variable.
```

In nib it is having two buttons for actions which I am setting actions like this.

```
 [(UIButton *)[toolBar viewWithTag:1234] addTarget:self action:@selector(goalTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [(UIButton *)[toolBar viewWithTag:12345] addTarget:self action:@selector(rewardsTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

These actions are triggering on iOS 11 even when I built with Xcode 8.3.3

But these actions are not triggering when i am building the application with XCode 9.

what could be the reason?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is `toolbar` (or is `toolBar`?) non-nil? Does `[toolBar viewWithTag:1234]` return a non-nil value?

Comment: I have already debugged it nothing is nil here even toolbar and button with tag. As i have already mentioned it is happening only with combination iOS 11 SDK and Xcode 9

Comment: And with Xcode 9, nothing is `nil`?

Comment: hmm with Xcode 9 nothing nil.

Comment: When did you load the toolbar and add target? like `awakeFromNib`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but when I changed from UIToolBar to UIView it started working.

Issue is specific to Xcode 9 and iOS 11 SDK.